# I need to redirect a file from server to a folder without htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i have a file on my "website/folder/file" which i would like to redirect to prevent user to access that file, without using htaccess.
My file is a huge DB containing url's,  i don't want the users access to that file by typing the direct URL to the file.
That file is called & used by my chrome extension, who block access to the user if he tries to reach one of the url's in that DB.
Problem is by typing the direct url to that file we have access...

i tried everything with the .htaccess file, i know we can block, redirect, etc with the .htaccess file but if i redirect or block the url of the DB with the htaccess, my extension doesn't work anymore because the DB is blocked by the htaccess file. 
so i'm trying to find a solution, maybe is an !

my background.js

```
'use strict';
let db = []; // session Global
// ----- parse & cache the database data
fetch('http://thmywebsite.com/folder/db.dat')
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => { db = text.trim().split(/[\r\n]+/); })
.catch(error => console.log(error));
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(details => {
let url = new URL(details.url);
return { cancel: url && url.hostname && db.includes(url.hostname) };
},
{ urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"] },
["blocking"]
);
chrome.extension.isAllowedIncognitoAccess(function (isAllowedAccess) {
if (isAllowedAccess) return; // Great, we've got access
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't realistically do this. You can't block a resource that needs to be available publicly (by your client-side script).

You can potentially make this a little *harder* for someone wanting your DB, by perhaps sending a unique HTTP request header as part of your `fetch()`. You can then check for the presence of this header server-side (in `.htaccess`) and block the request otherwise. This prevents a user from *casually* requesting this file directly in their browser. However, this is trivial to bypass for anyone who looks at your script (or monitors the network traffic) as they can construct the request to mimic your script. But let's not forget, your script downloads the file to the browser anyway - so it's already there for anyone to save.

You need to rethink your data model. If you don't want the DB to be publicly accessible then it simply can't be publicly accessible. Instead of your script downloading the DB to the client and processing the request locally, you could send the request to your server. Your *server* then performs the necessary lookup (on the "hidden" database) and sends back a response. Your script then acts on this response.

Comment: Thanks for the infos, it is complex to achieve that ?

Comment: Not really. No more complex than your current solution, just different. It requires a bit of server-side scripting in addition to your client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Because i don't know how to achieve that with my current background.js

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on specifically? You obviously need to rewrite your `background.js` script, but I don't think the core principles are really any different. Instead of `fetch()` your entire DB file at the start of the script and using JS to lookup the URL. You `fetch()` your server-side script in the event listener and pass the URL, either as a URL param, or custom header. Your server-side script (PHP, python, C#?) then looks the URL up in the DB (if this is "huge" then you will get better performance using a relational DB) and sends the _boolean_ response back to the client.

Comment: yeah the db is huge 5mb +300.000 url's stored in text format inside the .db file, like: www.badurl01.com   badurl01.com etc im happy to see a solution exist to my problem, now i don't know how to do that from the server side !